# CGContextRef - EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I am subclassing UIView and using instances of that to set my UITableViewCell backgroundView and selectedBackedView properties. I am receiving an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in the drawRect method of my UIView subclass.

```
    if(nil == cell){

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.backgroundView = [[CCViewBackground alloc]init];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[CCViewBackground alloc]init];

    }
```

UIView subclass CCBackgroundView  -drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
     // Drawing code
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

     CGColorRef redColor = 
     [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

     CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, redColor); //Receiving EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
     CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);

}
```

Comment: can you enable NSZombie for your app and share the reason for receiving EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: This is now the error message with NSZombie enabled -  *** -[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x109b50

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using ARC. If so, you are running into a well-known problem where the `CGColorRef` is released earlier than you expect. [This article](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/arc-gotcha-unexpectedly-short-lifetimes/) explains the problem in detail and provides several solutions.

Comment: Yes, I am using arc. Thanks for the article, it fixed the issue

Comment: Praise the Internets! This solved it, thanks for the article!

Comment: Can someone please share the link for article again...it is broken link now.